# How to write this select statement that counts if profit is < 55% of the cost of the item?

Tags: sql, database

I'm a new student to database and I've come across a question in my book that I'm having a hard time solving. Pretending I'm the DBA of this bookstore...

I need to determine which books are generating less than 55% profit and how many copies of the books have been sold. Here is what I have tried doing:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(*)
FROM books
WHERE (retail-cost) >= .55 * cost group by title;
```

But when I run that, I just get this:

```
DATABASE IMPLEMENTATION 1
PAINLESS CHILD-REARING  1
HOW TO GET FASTER PIZZA 1
SHORTEST POEMS  1
BIG BEAR AND LITTLE DOVE    1
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY   1
HOLY GRAIL OF ORACLE    1
HOW TO MANAGE THE MANAGER   1
COOKING WITH MUSHROOMS  1
BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS  1
```

Clearly, it's not right. How do I do this?

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Books 
(ISBN VARCHAR2(10), 
Title VARCHAR2(30), 
PubDate DATE, 
PubID NUMBER (2), 
Cost NUMBER (5,2), 
Retail NUMBER (5,2), 
Discount NUMBER (4,2),
Category VARCHAR2(12),
  CONSTRAINT books_isbn_pk PRIMARY KEY(isbn),
   CONSTRAINT books_pubid_fk FOREIGN KEY (pubid)
     REFERENCES publisher (pubid));

CREATE TABLE ORDERITEMS 
 ( Order# NUMBER(4),
   Item# NUMBER(2),
   ISBN VARCHAR2(10),
   Quantity NUMBER(3) NOT NULL, 
   PaidEach NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT orderitems_pk PRIMARY KEY (order#, item#),
   CONSTRAINT orderitems_order#_fk FOREIGN KEY (order#)
         REFERENCES orders (order#) ,
   CONSTRAINT orderitems_isbn_fk FOREIGN KEY (isbn)
         REFERENCES books (isbn) ,
   CONSTRAINT oderitems_quantity_ck CHECK (quantity > 0) );
```

Comment: The where statement looks wrong: I'm assuming that the retail-cost and cost are two separate fields ?

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: you want to count the number of sales , I guess it's located in anaother table

Comment: @scraaappy I added the tables I think I need. I would just have to COUNT(isbn) you think?

Comment: Which table do you store `retail-cost`?

Comment: @sqluser It's just an operation I did on my books table. I have the table structure posted up there and you could see retail and cost in there.

Comment: Some data and a desired result would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a join to see how many of your books has been sold

```
SELECT b.ISBN, b.Title, COUNT(ISBN)
FROM books AS b
INNER JOIN ORDERITEMS AS oi ON oi.ISBN = b.ISBN
WHERE Retail >= .55 * Cost
GROUP BY b.ISBN, b.Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your posted request `... count(*)... group by title` returns the number of rows for each title in the table Books, that' s why you always obtain 1.
What you want is to sum the quantity in orderItems, and get the title with isbn matching value in table books. I would do something like this :

```
select Books.title, sum(ORDERITEMS.Quantity) as numberOfSales from ORDERITEMS
left join Books
on ORDERITEMS.isbn = Books.isbn and Books.cost <= (retail-cost/.55)
group by title
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this statement:

```
SELECT Title, COUNT(*)
FROM books
WHERE (retail-cost) >= (0.55 * (retail-cost))
group by Title;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT ISBN,TITLE,SUM(QUANTITY)
 FROM BOOKS JOIN ORDERITEMS USING(ISBN)
 WHERE (RETAIL-COST)/COST<.55
 GROUP BY ISBN, TITLE
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)